# Segue from a UICollectionView in Swift

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, swift2

This question probably has an extremely simple answer, but I can't get my head around it. Nor can I find a particularly useful answer that works anywhere online.

I simply can't get a segue working from a UICollectionViewCell. I'm possibly coming at it from the wrong angle, as I assumed it worked in a very similar way to a table view segue. Working on that premise, if I was using a table view, it would look something like this:

```
if segue.identifier == "TripsToPastTripDetailsSegue" {
        let newViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! pastTripDetailViewController
        let selectedRow: NSManagedObject = tripsList[tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow!.row] as NSManagedObject
        newViewController.passedTrip = selectedRow as! Trips   
    }
```

So, with the table view I would be passing a single object (from Core Data) over to the another view controller. Simple. But I just can't translate that over to a collection view.

I have been attempting something along these lines:

```
if segue.identifier == "pastTripCollectionToSavedLocationSegue" {
        let newViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! pastTripDetailViewController
        let selectedRow: NSManagedObject = locationsList[collectionView.indexPathForCell(pastLocationImageCollectionViewCell)] as! NSManagedObject
        newViewController.passedTrip = selectedRow as! Trips   
    }
```

But this gives me an error of **Cannot find member 'indexPathForCell'**, so I'm obviously doing something very wrong. This is one of many errors I've had whilst playing around with the code.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

EDIT:

As requested by @Laffen, the UICollectionView appears in the following locations in the code:

```
class pastTripDetailViewController: UIViewController,  UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate, MKMapViewDelegate {
```

As an IBOutlet:

```
@IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!
```

Data source and delegate in ViewDidLoad:

```
self.collectionView.dataSource = self
self.collectionView.delegate = self
```

And here's the rest:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfSectionsInCollectionView indexPath: Int) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return self.locationsList.count
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let location = self.locationsList[indexPath.row]
    let cell: pastLocationImageCollectionViewCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("imageCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! pastLocationImageCollectionViewCell
    cell.locationImage.image = UIImage(data: location.image!)

    return cell
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    performSegueWithIdentifier("pastTripCollectionToSavedLocationSegue", sender: self)
}
```

Comment: Where do you initialize the `collectionView` and is it in fact an `UICollectionView` ?

Comment: @Laffen, I've added the rest of the code related to the collectionView.

Comment: I've updated my answer.. I think it should work

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maybe this could work for you:

```
let indexPath: NSIndexPath = self.collectionView.indexPathsForSelectedItems().first!
let selectedRow: NSManagedObject = locationsList[indexPath] as! NSManagedObject
```

This will only work if the `locationsList` is of type dictionary and is initialized like this:

```
var locationsList = [NSIndexPath: NSManagedObject]()
```

Hope this is helpful

Edit:

It seems you are trying to pass along the `pastLocationImageCollectionViewCell` type in the `indexPathForCell`. The argument must be an instance of the type `pastLocationImageCollectionViewCell`.

Try this:

Edited: example below will only work as desired when having only one section in the UICollectionView.

```
func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "pastTripCollectionToSavedLocationSegue" {
        let newViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! pastTripDetailViewController
        let indexPath = sender as! NSIndexPath
        let selectedRow: NSManagedObject = locationsList[indexPath.row] as! NSManagedObject
        newViewController.passedTrip = selectedRow as! Trips   
    }
}

// Set the indexPath of the selected item as the sender for the segue
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    performSegueWithIdentifier("pastTripCollectionToSavedLocationSegue", sender: indexPath)
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Laffen, but now I'm getting another error - `Cannot subscript a value of type '[Locations]' with an index of type 'NSIndexPath'` on line 5 of your answer. :/

Comment: As i pointed out in my answer, to be able to use the entire NSIndexPath object as an index parameter, the locations array have to be a dictionary with NSIndexPath as the key and Coordinates as the value. However.. If you're using only one section, just write `indexPath.row` as the array accessor.

Answer (score 2):

**Try it.**

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
self.performSegueWithIdentifier("yourSegueIdentifier", sender: self)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code, put it in the class of the collectionview (Swift 4, xcode 9)

```
  func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
            print("cell clicked")
  let singleDetail = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "urDestinationViewControllerIdentifier") as? urDestinationViewControllerClass
        singleDetail?.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
        self.present(singleDetail!, animated: true) {() -> Void in }
        }
```